# Phone Icon Shows 4 Voicemails on Erased iPhone

Tags: iphone, voicemail

So one of my users at work recently got a new iPhone 8+ to replace her older but still functional iPhone 6s+. She just turned it in and asked that I wipe the phone of all of her data.

He account has already been moved from the old phone to the new one via AT&T's [online setup page](https://www.att.com/checkmyorder/activations/activateWireless.rt).

It was purchased through our work account and you just enter the phone number for the account being transferred and the billing zip code and then you power cycle both phones.

When that is done the old phone displays "No Service" where the new phone shows AT&T. Essentially deactivating the SIM card in the old phone.

### Here's where it gets strange...

I wiped the phone: `Settings > General > Reset > Erase all content and settings`

And when I went back into the phone (going through the setup procedure to set up as a new phone) the phone icon shows the red indicator dot with a "4" in it indicating that there are 4 voicemails.

If I go into Phone > Voicemail the red "4" dot shows over the voicemail icon, bottom right, and all I can do is exit out of the phone.app or tap the "call voicemail" button in the middle of the screen, which just takes me to a gray screen that says "VOIOCEMAIL Call Failed" with the option to try again or cancel.

We use these phones as loaners when someone loses or breaks their iPhone until we can get them a new one, so I have to get this ready to to be rolled out to someone on a moments notice, which involves swapping in their old SIM (if available) and signing them into to their AppleID and mail accounts. But **there seems to be no way to delete the old voicemails, still on the device.**

Any ideas how I might approach that?

Comment: Aren't the VMs tied to the phone numbers?  Wiping the phone doesn't delete the phone number associated with it.  Can you [call the iPhone's number from a different phone](https://www.att.com/esupport/article.html#!/wireless/KM1009101) and access the VMs to delete them?

Comment: The phone has no service and an "expired" SIM It *HAS* no phone number. The one that was associated with this phone is now in use by another phone.

Comment: I get that, I was just figuring that the iPhone is/was notified of the VMs somehow so deleting the VMs from the account might fix it.  Otherwise, you might need to contact ATT because the SIM is somehow still seeing VMs even though it's expired.